# Replacing bash variables in a stream

Tags: bash, variables, replace

Is there an easy way to replace all occurences of variables in a stream?

So let's say i have a file with contents.

```
$FOO $BAR $BAZ
```

And i want to do something like

```
less file | replaceVars | process
```

The replaceVars step should replace all references to the variables with their values. I'd like to not have to specify the variables i want to replace (like i would need when using sed or something similar). Is there somewhere a built-in function or small program that allows me to use the bash parser or something to do this replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval`:

```
while read -r line; do eval echo "${line}"; done < inputfile | process
```

This would expand the variables in the inputfile before piping the output to the process.

Answer (score 3):

Create a function like this

```
function replaceVars {
    local V IFS=
    while read -r LINE; do
        for V; do
            LINE=${LINE//"$V"/"${!V}"}
        done
        echo "$LINE"
    done
}
```

And you can call it on a stream like this:

```
cat file | replaceVars FOO BAR BAZ | process
```

I replaced `cat` with `less` since `less` doesn't really interact with stdout but the terminal itself. You could do this instead as well:

```
replaceVars FOO BAR BAZ < file | process
```

If you want to store those variable names in an array you can do it like this:

```
VARS=(FOO BAR BAZ)
replaceVars "${VARS[@]}" < file | process
```

By the way make sure you run it as Bash. A complete script example for it could be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

VARS=(FOO BAR BAZ)

function replaceVars {
    local V IFS=
    while read -r LINE; do
        for V; do
            LINE=${LINE//"$V"/"${!V}"}
        done
    done
    echo "$LINE"
}

replaceVars "${VARS[@]}" < file | process
```